# MySQL server 8.0.15 writing configuration file failed invalid server template

Tags: mysql, sql

after downloading and installing all files this log stops at the first step.
any help?

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Invalid server template

Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Comment: If your question is about MySQL, then why did you tag your question with sql-server (which is for Microsoft SQL Server questions)?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this but the installer is labeled mysql server 8.0.15

Comment: And that makes it MySQL, not SQL Server...